# Перехват HttpRequest в Netty 4?

Tags: java, http, netty

Пишу мультиплеер на игру крестики-нолики через браузер. Решил использовать Netty 4.0.51 и у меня возникла сложность в написании перехватчика. Не могу перехватить HttpRequest для определения ответа от клиента.

```
public class TicTacToeServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            handleHttpRequest(ctx, (HttpRequest) msg);
        } else if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
            handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
        }
    }
```

При дебаге значение

```
Object msg = "GET /websocket HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
```

По идее он должен определять его как `HttpRequest` и вызывать мой метод, но этого почему-то не происходит. Может кто-то плотно работает с Netty и может подсказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Netty есть немало классов облегчающих типовые задачи. В частности [HttpServerCodec](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpServerCodec.html) и [HttpObjectAggregator](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectAggregator.html) позволят вызывать обработчик в тот момент, когда сервер получит запрос полностью. Кроме того, лучше разнести обработку http-запросов и обработку websocket-фреймов в разные классы:

```
public class WebServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        // Кодек протокола HTTP
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        // Собираем отдельные пакеты в полный http-запрос
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
        // Наш обработчик http
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpRequestHandler());
        // Обработчик websocket-запросов
        pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/websocket"));
        // Наш обработчик websocket
        pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketFrameHandler());
    }
}

public class HttpRequestHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {
    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest request) {
        QueryStringDecoder queryDecoder = new QueryStringDecoder(request.uri(), true);
        if ("/websocket".equalsIgnoreCase(queryDecoder.path())) {
            // Пробрасываем на обработчик websocket'ов
            ctx.fireChannelRead(request.retain());
        }
        else {
            // Обрабатываем обычный http-запрос
        }
    }
}

public class TextWebSocketFrameHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<TextWebSocketFrame> {
    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt == WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.ServerHandshakeStateEvent.HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE) {
            // Если прошёл хэндшейк websocket'а,
            // удаляем обработчик обычных http-запросов,
            // чтобы не вносил задержку в обработку запросов
            ctx.pipeline().remove(HttpRequestHandler.class);
        } else {
            super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, TextWebSocketFrame msg) {
        // Обрабатываем фрейм
    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично. Помогло добавление кодека HTTP. Но при переходе на `localhost:port` возникает исключение `io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade`

Comment: Моя невнимательность! Пропустил добавление одного важного обработчика в пайплайн. Исправил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Все-равно падает с таким исключением. Я наткнулся на решение разработчика [ссылка](https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/7ef6db3ffd2f10cce835685359dec642bd3c874c), но я не понимаю, что нужно сделать)

Comment: А netty у вас какой версии? 4.0 или 4.1?

Comment: Версия 4.1.15.Final

Comment: Очень странно. Судя по ошибке, на последний обработчик в цепочке каким-то образом проходят не websocket-запросы.

Answer (score 1):

Прикреплю код, если будет время, то посмотрите. Я пока не разносил в отдельные классы обработчики.

```
public class TicTacToeServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    private static Map<Integer, TicTacToeGame> games = new HashMap<>();

    private static final String WEBSOCKET_PATH = "/websocket";

    private WebSocketServerHandshaker handshaker;

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            handleHttpRequest(ctx, (HttpRequest) msg);
        } else if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
            handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
        }
    }

    private void handleHttpRequest(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {

        if (req.method() != HttpMethod.GET) {
            sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.FORBIDDEN));
            return;
        }

        WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory wsFactory = new WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory(this.getWebSocketLocation(req), null, false);
        this.handshaker = wsFactory.newHandshaker(req);
        if (this.handshaker == null) {
            wsFactory.sendUnsupportedVersionResponse(ctx.channel());
        } else {

            this.handshaker.handshake(ctx.channel(), req);
            initGame(ctx);
        }
    }

    private void initGame(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        TicTacToeGame game = findGame();
        Player player = new Player(ctx.channel());
        TicTacToeGame.PlayerLetter letter = game.addPlayer(player);
        games.put(game.getId(), game);
        ctx.channel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(new HandshakeMessage(game.getId(), letter.toString()).toJson()));
        if (game.getStatus() == TicTacToeGame.Status.IN_PROGRESS) {
            game.getPlayer(PlayerLetter.X).getChannel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(new TurnMessage(YOUR_TURN).toJson()));
            game.getPlayer(PlayerLetter.O).getChannel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(new TurnMessage(WAITING).toJson()));
        }
    }

    private TicTacToeGame findGame() {
        for (TicTacToeGame g : games.values()) {
            if (g.getStatus().equals(TicTacToeGame.Status.WAITING)) {
                return g;
            }
        }
        return new TicTacToeGame();
    }

    private void handleWebSocketFrame(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) {
        if (frame instanceof CloseWebSocketFrame) {
            this.handshaker.close(ctx.channel(), (CloseWebSocketFrame) frame);
            return;
        } else if (frame instanceof PingWebSocketFrame) {
            ctx.channel().write(new PongWebSocketFrame(frame.content()));
            return;
        } else if (!(frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame)) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("%s frame types not supported", frame.getClass().getName()));
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        IncomingMessage message = gson.fromJson(((TextWebSocketFrame) frame).text(), IncomingMessage.class);

        TicTacToeGame game = games.get(message.getGameId());
        Player opponent = game.getOpponent(message.getPlayer());
        Player player = game.getPlayer(PlayerLetter.valueOf(message.getPlayer()));
        game.markCell(message.getGridIdAsInt(), player.getLetter());
        boolean winner = game.isPlayerWinner(player.getLetter());
        boolean tied = game.isTied();
        String responseToOpponent = new OutgoingMessage(player.getLetter().toString(), message.getGridId(), winner, tied).toJson();
        opponent.getChannel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(responseToOpponent));
        if (winner) {
            player.getChannel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(new GameOverMessage(YOU_WIN).toJson()));
        } else if (tied) {
            player.getChannel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(new GameOverMessage(TIED).toJson()));
        }
    }

    private void sendHttpResponse(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req, FullHttpResponse res) {
        if (res.status().code() != 200) {
            ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(res.status().toString(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            res.content().writeBytes(buf);
        }
        ChannelFuture f = ctx.channel().write(res);
        if (!HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(req) || res.status().code() != 200) {
            f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    private String getWebSocketLocation(HttpRequest req) {
        String protocol = "ws";
        return protocol + "://" + req.headers().get(HOST) + WEBSOCKET_PATH;
    }
}
```

Класс инициализатор

```
public class TicTacToeServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline channelPipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
        channelPipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        channelPipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
        channelPipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        channelPipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        channelPipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/websocket"));
        channelPipeline.addLast("handler", new TicTacToeServerHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем StringDecoder и StringEncoder?